# express-stormpath email verfication

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath, express-stormpath

when the user submits his data always get this error
Property name 'emailVerificationToken' is not defined in profile
I checked everything in docs ,I cannot found any related solution
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {

expand: {
  customData: true,
  groups: true,
  groupMemberships: true,
  providerData: true
},
web: {
verifyEmail: {
  enabled: true,
  nextUri: 'http://localhost:3001/login'
},
  login: {
    form: {
      fields: {
        login: {
          label: 'Email',
          placeholder: 'Email'
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          placeholder: 'Password'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  register: {
    enabled: true,
    autoLogin: true,
    uri: '/signup',  // Use a different URL
    nextUri: '/',    // Where to send the user to, if auto login is enabled
    form: {
      fields: {
        surname: {enabled: false},
        givenName: {
          enabled: true,
          label: 'Username',
          placeholder: 'Username',
          required: true,
          type: 'text'
        },
      },
      fieldOrder: ['givenName', 'email', 'password']
    }
  }
},
preRegistrationHandler: function (formData, req, res, next) {
        console.log(formData)
        return next();
        }
      });
    });
},
postRegistrationHandler: function (account, req, res, next) {
    console.log("account")
  next();
},
apiToken: "",
org: '',
application : {
  id : ""
}
}));
```